# Dataset API, Iterators and tf.contrib.data.rejection_resample

Tags: tensorflow, iterator

**[Edit #1 after @mrry comment]**
I am using the (great & amazing) Dataset API along with tf.contrib.data.rejection_resample
to set a specific distribution function to the input training pipeline.

Before adding the tf.contrib.data.rejection_resample to the input_fn  I used the one shot Iterator. Alas, when starting to use the latter, I tried using the dataset.make_initializable_iterator() - This is because we are introducing to the pipeline stateful variables, and one is required to initialize the iterator AFTER all variables in the input pipeline are init. 
As @mrry wrote [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44504063/8096451)

I am passing the input_fn to an estimator and wrapped by an Experiment.

Problem is - where to hook the init of the iterator?
If I try:

```
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
if self.balance:
   dataset = tf.contrib.data.rejection_resample(dataset, self.class_mapping_function, self.dist_target)
   iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
   tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TABLE_INITIALIZERS, iterator.initializer)
else:
   iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator() 

image_batch, label_batch = iterator.get_next()
print (image_batch)
```

and the mapping function:

```
def class_mapping_function(self, feature, label):
    """
    returns a a function to be used with dataset.map() to return class numeric ID
    The function is mapping a nested structure of tensors (having shapes and types defined by dataset.output_shapes
    and dataset.output_types) to a scalar tf.int32 tensor. Values should be in [0, num_classes).
    """
    # For simplicity, trying to return the label itself as I assume its numeric...

    return tf.cast(label, tf.int32)  # <-- I guess this is the bug
```

the iterator does not receive the Tensor shape as it does with one shot iterator.

For Example.
With One Shot iterator run, the iterator gets correct shape:

```
Tensor("train_input_fn/IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(?, 100, 100, 3), dtype=float32, device=/device:CPU:0)
```

But when using the initializable iterator, it is missing tensor shape info:

```
Tensor("train_input_fn/IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32, device=/device:CPU:0)
```

Any help will be so appreciated!

[**Edit #2** ]- following @mrry comment that it seems like another dataset]
Perhaps the real issue here is not the init sequence of the iterator but the mapping function used by tf.contrib.data.rejection_resample that returns tf.int32. But then I wonder how the mapping function should be defined ? To keep the dataset shape as (?,100,100,3) for example...

[**Edit #3**]: From the implementation of rejection_resample

```
class_values_ds = dataset.map(class_func)
```

So it makes sense the class_func will take a dataset and return a dataset of tf.int32.

Comment: Can you share the code? It looks like the two iterators are created from two different `Dataset` objects, which might explain why they have different inferred shapes (and types!).

Comment: Hi @mrry. Thanks for replying so quickly ! I added all the info, and I think you definitely found the problem. I believe its not the init process but rather a misuse of the mapping function in the tf.contrib.data.rejection_resample. If you agree this is the reason - I will be so grateful if you can comment on how one should define the mapping function as I could not find a reference for this. Thank you ! –

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using tensorflow dataset with stratified sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53505150/using-tensorflow-dataset-with-stratified-sampling)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Following @mrry response I could come up with a solution on how to use the Dataset API with tf.contrib.data.rejection_resample (using TF1.3).

**The goal**

Given a feature/label dataset with some distribution, have the input pipeline reshape the distribution to specific target distribution.

**Numerical example**

Lets assume we are building a network to classify some feature into one of 10 classes. 
And assume we only have 100 features with some random distribution of labels.
30 features labeled as class 1, 5 features labeled as class 2
and so forth. 
During training we do not want to prefer class 1 over class 2 so we would like each mini-batch to hold a uniform distribution for all classes.

**The solution**

Using tf.contrib.data.rejection_resample will allow to set a specific distribution for our inputs pipelines.

In the documentation it says tf.contrib.data.rejection_resample will take

(1) Dataset - which is the dataset you want to balance

(2) class_func - which is a function that generates a new numerical labels dataset only from the original dataset

(3) target_dist - a vector in the size of the number of classes to specificy required new distribution.

(4) some more optional values  - skipped for now

and as the documentation says it returns a `Dataset.

It turns out that the shape of the input Dataset is different than the output Dataset shape. As a consequence, **the returned Dataset (as implemeted in TF1.3) should be filtered by the user like this:**

```
    balanced_dataset = tf.contrib.data.rejection_resample(input_dataset,
                                                          self.class_mapping_function,
                                                          self.target_distribution)

    # Return to the same Dataset shape as was the original input
    balanced_dataset = balanced_dataset.map(lambda _, data: (data))
```

One note on the Iterator kind. 
As @mrry explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44504063/8096451), when using stateful objects within the pipeline one should use the initializable iterator and not the one-hot. Note that when using the initializable iterator you should add the init_op to the TABLE_INITIALIZERS or you will recieve this error: "GetNext() failed because the iterator has not been initialized."

Code example:

```
# Creating the iterator, that allows to access elements from the dataset
if self.use_balancing:
    # For balancing function, we use stateful variables in the sense that they hold current dataset distribution
    # and calculate next distribution according to incoming examples.
    # For dataset pipeline that have state, one_shot iterator will not work, and we are forced to use
    # initializable iterator
    # This should be relaxed in the future.
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44374083/tensorflow-cannot-capture-a-stateful-node-by-value-in-tf-contrib-data-api
    iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TABLE_INITIALIZERS, iterator.initializer)

else:
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

image_batch, label_batch = iterator.get_next()
```

**Does it work ?**

Yes. 
Here are 2 images from Tensorboard after collection a histogram on the input pipeline labels. 
The original input labels were uniformly distributed.
Scenario A: Trying to achieve the following 10-class distribution:
[0.1,**0.4**,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.1,0.1]

And the result:

[image]

Scenario B: Trying to achieve the following 10-class distribution:
[0.1,0.1,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,**0.4**,0.1]

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Outstanding post explaining exactly the issue I'm having. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is below a simple example to demonstrate the usage of [sample_from_datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/sample_from_datasets) (thanks @Agade for the idea).

```py
import math
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def print_dataset(name, dataset):
    elems = np.array([v.numpy() for v in dataset])
    print("Dataset {} contains {} elements :".format(name, len(elems)))
    print(elems)


def combine_datasets_balanced(dataset_smaller, size_smaller, dataset_bigger, size_bigger, batch_size):
    ds_smaller_repeated = dataset_smaller.repeat(count=int(math.ceil(size_bigger / size_smaller)))
    # we repeat the smaller dataset so that the 2 datasets are about the same size
    balanced_dataset = tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets([ds_smaller_repeated, dataset_bigger], weights=[0.5, 0.5])
    # each element in the resulting dataset is randomly drawn (without replacement) from dataset even with proba 0.5 or from odd with proba 0.5
    balanced_dataset = balanced_dataset.take(2 * size_bigger).batch(batch_size)
    return balanced_dataset


N, M = 3, 10
even = tf.data.Dataset.range(0, 2 * N, 2).repeat(count=int(math.ceil(M / N)))
odd = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 2 * M, 2)
even_odd = combine_datasets_balanced(even, N, odd, M, 2)

print_dataset("even", even)
print_dataset("odd", odd)
print_dataset("even_odd_all", even_odd)
```

```
Output :

Dataset even contains 12 elements :  # 12 = 4 x N  (because of .repeat)
[0 2 4 0 2 4 0 2 4 0 2 4]
Dataset odd contains 10 elements :
[ 1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19]
Dataset even_odd contains 10 elements :  # 10 = 2 x M / 2  (2xM because of .take(2 * M) and /2 because of .batch(2))
[[ 0  2]
 [ 1  4]
 [ 0  2]
 [ 3  4]
 [ 0  2]
 [ 4  0]
 [ 5  2]
 [ 7  4]
 [ 0  9]
 [ 2 11]]
```