# Using rejection_resample() with the Dataset Api

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am having a hard time trying to make some balancing batching using the rejection_resample() along with the Dataset API. I am using images and labels (ints) as input, as you can glance in the code, but the **rejection_resample()** seems not to work as expected.

**Note: I am using Tensorflow v1.3**

Here I define the dataset, the dataset's distribution and the distribution I want.

```
target_dist = [0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9]
initial_dist = [0.1061, 0.3213, 0.4238, 0.1203, 0.0282]

training_filenames = training_records
training_dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(training_filenames)
training_dataset = training_dataset.map(tf_record_parser)  # Parse the record into tensors.
training_dataset = training_dataset.repeat()  # number of epochs
training_dataset = training_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)

training_dataset = tf.contrib.data.rejection_resample(training_dataset,
                                                      class_func=lambda _, c: c,
                                                      target_dist=target_dist,
                                                      initial_dist=initial_dist)

# Return to the same Dataset shape as was the original input
training_dataset = training_dataset.map(lambda _, data: (data))

training_dataset = training_dataset.batch(64)

handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
iterator = tf.contrib.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(
    handle, training_dataset.output_types, training_dataset.output_shapes)
batch_images, batch_labels = iterator.get_next()
training_iterator = training_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
```

When I run this thing I should only get samples from the classes 0 and 4, but I get results from all of the classes, as though it did not work.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    training_handle = sess.run(training_iterator.string_handle())
    sess.run(training_iterator.initializer)
    batch_faces_np, batch_label_np = sess.run([batch_images, batch_labels],feed_dict={handle: training_handle})

    ctr = Counter(batch_label_np)
```

> Counter({2: 31, 3: 22, 4: 6, 1: 5})

I tested with an example based on this post: [Dataset API, Iterators and tf.contrib.data.rejection_resample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039760/dataset-api-iterators-and-tf-contrib-data-rejection-resample) and from the original testing code from the tensorflow repo and it works.

```
initial_known = True
classes = np.random.randint(5, size=(20000,))  # Uniformly sampled
target_dist = [0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4]
initial_dist = [0.2] * 5 if initial_known else None

iterator = dataset_ops.Iterator.from_dataset(
    dataset_ops.rejection_resample(
        (dataset_ops.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(classes)
         .shuffle(200, seed=21)
         .map(lambda c: (c, string_ops.as_string(c)))),
        target_dist=target_dist,
        initial_dist=initial_dist,
        class_func=lambda c, _: c,
        seed=27))
init_op = iterator.initializer
get_next = iterator.get_next()
variable_init_op = variables.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(variable_init_op)
    sess.run(init_op)
    returned = []
    while True:
        returned.append(sess.run(get_next))
```

> Counter({(0, (0, b'0')): 3873, (4, (4, b'4')): 3286})

Can you guys help me with that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with seed value for shuffle.
It worked with seed value for me.

Comment: Yes, that was it! Strange enough, we need to specify the seed value in the shuffle function just as the example I should above. Thanks!